# Convert Data Frames into One Column Vector

Tags: r, dataframe, standard-deviation

I have an 11 x 8 data frame of numeric values in R that I want to find the standard deviation of. However, I cannot take the standard deviation of a matrix (use the sd() function), only the columns. But I need every data value used. How do I make this data frame into one column so that all values are used when finding the standard deviation? Hope this makes sense.

[image]

Comment: If your matrix is `x` then do `sd(as.vector(x))`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that. I got an error that says (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: Please post your data to see what the issue is.

Comment: what about `sd(unlist(x))`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks, unlist function works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
#generate data
df <- data.frame(matrix(rbinom(8*11, 1, .5), ncol=8))

#get sd
sd(unlist(df))
```

edit: just saw the comment where user fra got there first